# How to define the format a string Parameter must take?

Tags: apiblueprint

We have a querystring parameter called imageDimensions, which specifies the desired dimensions for images of different types.
e.g. `?imageDimensions=poster:600x800,badge:100x100`

Is there a way in API Blueprint to specify that imageDimensions should be a comma-separated list of image dimension specs, each of form "(image type):(width)x(height)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good dedicated syntax for it at the moment. I would probably go with something like:

```
## GET /resource{?imageDimensions}
+ Parameters
    + imageDimensions (string, optional) - Comma-separated list of image dimension specs, each of form `(image type):(width)x(height)`

        Where the `(image type)` is one of the following:

        - badge
        - poster
        - icon

        + Sample: `badge:100x100`
        + Sample: `poster:600x800`
        + Sample: `poster:600x800,badge:100x100`

+ Response 200
```

Note, it is planned to move the parameters syntax to full [MSON syntax](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson) in the near future. See the API [Blueprint roadmap](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/286).

With it, it should be possible to define types for images as an `enum` and then reference it in the blueprint.